# Cannot mount cdrom drive

Tags: mount, xubuntu, cd-drive

I cannot mount cdrom drive on xubuntu 14.04. Here is my /etc/fstab :
Any suggestions ? (if you could also provide me a brief explanation, so that i can deal with it alone the next time.)

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=756c2256-0021-452f-b3b0-4b7f197a8570 /               ext4        errors=remoun$
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A892-4F23  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=5ef5ebbe-9be7-4587-81f0-01cfc46aaff3 none            swap            sw           $
# cdrom 0
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/  auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0
# cdrom 1
/dev/sr0 /media/cdrom/ auto ro,noauto,user,exec 0 0
```

Comment: You generally don't want to mount the cdrom from fstab, Doesn't xubuntu automatically mount it for you when you insert a CD/DVD?

Comment: no. Why wouldnt i?

Comment: Well generally in Graphical desktop environments like xubuntu the desktop enviroment takes care of mounting external media like USB/DVD for you.  FSTAB  is used to mount permanent storage like HDD, NFS etc.

Comment: Ok. What should i do now?

Comment: Take the line out of `/etc/fstab` re the cdrom and then reboot and try just inserting a cd and see if it auto mounts.

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thank you, its automatically mounted once rebooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in Graphical desktop environments like xubuntu the desktop environment takes care of mounting external media like USB/DVD for you. FSTAB is used to mount permanent storage like HDD, NFS.

Take the line out of `/etc/fstab` re the cdrom and then reboot and try just inserting a cd and see if it auto mounts.